# Haskell set datatype/datastructure

Tags: haskell, data-structures, set, compare, equals

What i want to do is to create a type Set in Haskell to represent a generic(polymorphic) set ex. `{1,'x',"aasdf",Phi}`

first i want to clear that in my program i want to consider Phi(Empty set) as something that belongs to all sets

here is my code

```
data Set a b= Phi | Cons a (Set a b)
deriving (Show,Eq,Ord)


isMember Phi _ = True
isMember _ Phi = False
isMember x (Cons a b) = if x==a
               then True
               else isMember x b
```

im facing a couple of problems:

1. I want `isMember` type to be

   ```
   isMember :: Eq a => a -> Set a b -> Bool
   ```

   but according to my code it is

   ```
   isMember :: Eq a => Set a b -> Set (Set a b) c -> Bool
   ```
2. If i have a set of different times the `==` operator doesn't work correctly so i need some help please :D

Comment: You have the empty set as a member of the empty set, which is a contradiction. Are you sure you're not confusing “is a *member* of” with “is a *subset* of”?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Regarding your type error, the problem looks like the first clause to me:

```
isMember Phi _ = True
```

This is an odd clause to write, because `Phi` is an entire set, not a set element. Just deleting it should give you a function of the type you expect.

Observe that your `Set` type never makes use of its second type argument, so it could be written instead as

```
data Set a = Phi | Cons a (Set a)
```

...and at that point you should just use `[a]`, since it's isomorphic and has a huge entourage of functions already written for using and abusing them.

Finally, you ask to be able to put things of different types in. The short answer is that Haskell doesn't really swing that way. It's all about knowing exactly what kind of type a thing is *at compile time*, which isn't really compatible with what you're suggesting. There are actually some ways to do this; however, I strongly recommend getting much more familiar with Haskell's particular brand of type bondage before trying to take the bonds off.

Comment: yes i knew that was the reason of the error, but i wanted it as a part of my program. I mixed between subset of and memeber of.

Answer (score 5):

A) Doing this is almost always not what you actually want.

B) There are a variety of ways to do this from embedding dynamic types (`Dynamic`) to using very complicated types (`HList`).

C) Here's a page describing some ways and issues: http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Heterogenous_collections

D) If you're really going to do this, I'd suggest `HList`: http://homepages.cwi.nl/~ralf/HList/

E) But if you start to look at the documentation / HList paper and find yourself hopelessly confused, fall back to the dynamic solution (or better yet, rethink why you need this) and come back to HLists once you're significantly more comfortable with Haskell.

(Oh yes, and the existential solution described on that page is probably a terrible idea, since it almost never does anything particularly useful for you).

Answer (score 2):

What you try to do is very difficult, as Haskell does not stores any type information by default. Two modules that are very useful for such things are [`Data.Typeable`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-Typeable.html) and [`Data.Dynamic`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-Dynamic.html). They provide support for storing a *monomorphic* (!) type and support for dynamic *monomorphic* typing.

I have not attempted to code something like  this previously, but I have some ideas to accomplish that:

1. Each element of your set is a triple (quadruple) of the following things:

   - A [`TypeRep`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-Typeable.html#t%3aTypeRep) of the stored data-type
   - The value itself, coerced into an [`Any`](http://haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.0-latest/html/libraries/ghc-prim-0.2.0.0/GHC-Prim.html#t%3aAny).
   - A comparison function (You can only use monomorphic values, you somehow have to store the context)
   - similary, a function to `show` the values.
2. Your set actually has two dimensions, first a tree by the `TypeRep` and than a list of values.
3. Whenever you insert a value, you coerce it into an `Any` and store all the required stuff together with it, as explained in (1) and put it in the right position as in (2).
4. When you want to find an element, you generate it's `TypeRep` and find the subtree of the right type. Then you just compare each sub-element with the value you want to find.

That are just some random thoughts. I guess it's actually much easier to use `Dynamic`.